# How to remove warnings[NOT by @SuppressWarnings ] in List and Iterator [What generic type to be applied on both line of code]

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hql

I want to remove warning by mentioning generic type in List result and Iterator orderRecord

OrderStorage class

```
public class OrderStorage {

    private static final String GET_TOTAL_ORDERS_QUERY = "SELECT c.name as customerName ,o.orderDate,p.name as productName  "
            + "FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Order o WITH o.customer = c LEFT JOIN Product p WITH o.product = p";

    public static List<TotalOrder> getOrder() {

        List<TotalOrder> resultList = new ArrayList<TotalOrder>();
        Session session = SessionCreator.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery(GET_TOTAL_ORDERS_QUERY).getResultList();
        Iterator orderRecord = result.iterator();
        while (orderRecord.hasNext()) { 
            TotalOrder customerOrder = new TotalOrder();
            Object values[] = (Object[]) orderRecord.next();
            customerOrder.setCustomerName(String.valueOf(values[0]));
            customerOrder.setOrderDate(String.valueOf(values[1]));
            customerOrder.setProductName(String.valueOf(values[2]));
            resultList.add(customerOrder);
        }
        session.close();
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

TotalOrder class

```
private String customerName;

private String orderDate;

private String productName;

Getters and Setters method
```

> **Warnings is :**
>
> List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be
>   parameterized
>
> Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator should
>   be parameterized

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a typed query by using another overload of createQuery method.

[Doc for createQuery method says:](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)

> ```
> <T> Query<T> createQuery(java.lang.String queryString,
>                          java.lang.Class<T> resultType)
> ```
>
> Create a typed Query instance for the given HQL/JPQL query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Object[]` or, probably better, use a `ResultTransformer`, that way you don't even need to use an iterator.

```
return session.createQuery(GET_TOTAL_ORDERS_QUERY)
         .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( TotalOrder.class ) )
         .getResultList();
```

This will let hibernate map the result directly to a `TotalOrder`, no need to map yourself. It might be needed to add an `as orderDate` to your query for the order field.

For more ways to map results check [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).